# Move window by dragging background (movableByWindowBackground)

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow

I have a window that I want users to be able to move by dragging anywhere in the window content (not just the titlebar).  I know that this can be done via the `NSWindow movableByWindowBackground` method, however this doesn't appear to work by itself.

I [gather](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563893/allow-click-and-dragging-a-view-to-drag-the-window-itself) that overriding `NSView mouseDownCanMoveWindow` may be necessary.  But I can't easily do that for all parent views (split views, etc).  Making it a textured window didn't help.  Unsurprisingly, subclassing `NSWindow` to override `isMovableByWindowBackground` didn't help either.

Is it really necessary to subclass all parent views in the window to make this work?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563893/allow-click-and-dragging-a-view-to-drag-the-window-itself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On OS X 10.11, setting the NSWindow's property `movableByWindowBackground` to `YES` works.

There is no longer any need to subclass for this behaviour.

Comment: In my experience, that's not the case. I have an NSSplitView that covers a window and I've set that property. The window is not draggable from background areas. I'm building against 10.11 and my deployment target is 10.11+

Comment: @Bryan consider logging a bug with Apple against `NSSplitView`; it sounds like unhandled mouse events are not being passed up through the `NSResponder` chain as expected.

Comment: I would say that's correct. I overrode -mouseDownCanMoveWindow in the splitView, returned YES, and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In NSSplitView you add:

```
override var mouseDownCanMoveWindow: Bool {
    return true
}
```